# OperationalError at /admin/ no such table: xadmin_usersettings

Tags: django, django-admin

I am getting the following error when open the admin panel of the project 
Note : Integrating django-xadmin.

> File "/project_path/project_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
>     323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>   Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/
>   Exception Value: no such table: xadmin_usersettings

Comment: Post your models and admin code

Comment: try to makemigrations xadmin and then migrate

Comment: check whether you have deleted migrations folder, this also causes OperationalError

Answer (score 2):

These came late,but it could be helpful to someone else

**1. Delete your database**

and rerun these commands in your command line;

**2. python manage.py makemigration**
 **3. python manage.py migrate**

*A new database is created, which clears the error*

happy coding...